# Can't find where this border comes from

Tags: css, border

I have gone up and down through the inspector... adding css on the fly, doing things... but yet I can't find how this border appears there...

[Border Image Presentation - Where this border comes from ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmRk1.jpg)

Anyone care to have a look and give an insight?

It looks like the border is surrounding the div with class "**`sports_main_content_inner"`**... but still it's unknown from where it comes from.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691, thanks for the recommendation - thinking to add relevant code - but what to include? there are various css files attached to the page and the infecting part could be anywhere...

Comment: Part of posting a question on SO should involve you troubleshooting and debugging your issue down to a bare minimum example. You'd be surprised at how often just doing this allows you to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by `.featured_article_section_main`. It's covering its whole container and has `border: solid 1px #dbdbdb;` applied.

Remove this div if not required, or set border to 0 to resolve.

Comment: Thanks.... adding a rule for border 0 to .featured_article_section_main solves it... but I am getting crazy... I can't spot this div anywhere in the source code. Can you point me?

Comment: It's inside `.modContent_Bottom`, which itself is inside `.sports_main_content_inner`

Comment: ok found it in the source... I ll take care - thanks for the catch.